# NestJS with TypeORM - Catch PostgreSQL unique_violation error on save()

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have got a function in a service that needs to get a value of a new or already existing object from the database and save it.

Issue is that `name` attribute of this object needs to be unique.

I know i can just create a `.some()` function over all database objects to check if i can enter this new value but its probably very unoptimal.

I would like to create somethign like this (below) but i have no idea what to do next:

```
const newObject = await this.repository
      .save({
        ...newObjectDto,
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err instanceof QueryFailedError) {
          // some code for err checking to make 
          // sure i only catch the unique_violation 
          // error and then throw error
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code for `unique_violation` is **23505**. You can check out the full list of error codes returned by PostgreSQL [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/errcodes-appendix.html).

In order to catch a unique constraint violation, you can do:

```
try {
  const newObject = await this.repository
    .save({
      ...newObjectDto,
    })
}
catch(err) {
  if (err instanceof QueryFailedError) {
    if(err.code === '23505') {
      console.log(`Unique constraint ${err.constraint} failed`);
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm a bit disappointed that there is still no easy cross-db handling for these magic error codes